# How do I expand on this one line Perl script to run a command until specific KEYWORD in output, then also play a sound?

Tags: perl, vpn, one-liner, mpv

I have a problem with my NordVPN account where I have to sometimes run the client upwards of 10 times, with their terrible CLI tool, until it finally successfully chooses a server that accepts my login.

I came across an old post here which I adapted to suit my needs, and it looks like this currently:

```
perl -e 'do { sleep(7); $_ = `nordvpn connect`; print $_; } until (m/connected/);'
```

It keeps running connect until it observes the word "connected" hopefully in the output.  But I want to expand this one step further.  When it successfully gets the keyword in the output, I want it then to 'mpv success.wav' or some similar thing, to play a simple .wav file located in the same directory.  mpv works great for this.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That loop quits when the condition is met so just add desired action(s) after the loop is done

```
perl -we'do { sleep(7); $_ = `nordvpn connect`; print $_; } 
    until (/connected/); system("mpv success.wav")'
```

This prints to screen whatever `mpv` does, what can be avoided for example by changing to

```
system("mpv success.wav > /dev/null 2>&1")
```

Here the `STDOUT` stream is [redirected](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) to the [null device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) (`/dev/null`) and then `STDERR` stream (file descriptor 2) is redirected to `STDOUT` (fd 1). So it all goes to the void.

Also, one can turn it around

```
perl -we'while (sleep 7) { 
    if (`nordvpn connect` =~ /connected/) { system("mpv success.wav"); last } }'
```

While this isn't as concise it is far more flexible for further changes. It does not print the command's return, as the original does.  That is easily added if it is really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `mpv success.wav` when `perl` exits.

```bash
perl -e'do { sleep 7; $_ = `nordvpn connect`; print; } until /connected/;'
mpv success.wav
```

If you want it all on one line, use a semi-colon.

```bash
perl -e'...'; mpv success.wav
```

Similar, but avoids playing the sound if `perl` is killed (e.g. using Ctrl-C).

```bash
perl -e'...' && mpv success.wav
```

---

If `nordvpn` sets exit code 0 when connected and non-zero otherwise, the Perl program can be simplified to the following:

```bash
perl -e'sleep 7 while system "nordvpn connect"'
```

If it doesn't set the exit code as described above, and if you don't care to see nordvpn's output, the Perl program can be simplified to the following:

```bash
perl -e'sleep 7 while `nordvpn connect` !~ /connected/'
```